# In what method should I recreate resources after didReceiveMemoryWarning?

Tags: iphone, ios, memory-management, uiviewcontroller

I have a view controller that has a private `NSArray` variable. The variable is initialised in the `viewDidLoad` method. A few questions arise for the case when the `didReceiveMemoryWarning` is called:

1. Should I set the private variable to `nil`?
2. If I set it to `nil` in what method must it be recreated? Does the view controller call the `viewDidLoad` method to recreate it?

I'm asking because other methods of the view need this variable and won't work if it's `nil`.

Thank you!

Comment: Why you want to set the NSArray *myArray;? Why it will call didReceiveMemoryWarning? If it's calling it's mean that there is a problem somewhere in your code you can use ARC

Comment: @arc didReceiveMemoryWarning is called when there is a low memory situation. It doesn't necessarily mean there is a bug in his code. The system could just have a lot going on.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Its better to set your variable to nil. I mean release the memory it is holding in `didReceiveMemoryWarning` and set a dirty flag.

You can always check the dirty flag in array's getter(you can write your own) and repopulate it. It is probably not the best way. It entirely depends on the array's usage.

Comment: So in theory if I set my variable to `nil` in the `didReceiveMemoryWarning` method I'll have to check for `nil` and repopulate before I try using it in any of my other methods. Is that correct?

Comment: Ya. you wouldn't want to access an nil array.

Comment: Down voting?. Any reason?.

Comment: -1. There's no need for a 'dirty' flag, just check for `nil` in the getter method.

Comment: @jlehr, Array can be nil for some other reason as well. There is no point in trying to repopulate it, if it is not done for memory warning. That's why I mentioned entirely depends on the usage. I appreciate your effort to correct the answer by the way,

Comment: @occulus, It answered the person asked the question. you can write a whole lecture about it, explaining what would happen in numerous other scenarios. Not doing that doesn't justify the negative voting.

Comment: It answers half the question, without giving any reason why the answer it proposes is good, and ignoring a whole load of nuances.

Comment: This question is very specific and focused. It answers what is been asked to the point. If you talk about nuances, there are hundreds, perhaps more. You cannot give a comprehensive guide. That's not the intention either. Your answer talks about few extra bits.That's all.  If you want to give additional info I appreciate it. It doesn't make my answer incorrect in anyway.

Answer (score 4):

Typically you unload a private property by assigning `nil` via the setter (e.g. `self.propertyName = nil`). Or you could set the ivar to nil after calling release, e.g. `[_propertyName release]; _propertyName = nil;`, but the former is preferable.

The `didReceiveMemoryWarning` method is called when there is a low memory situation. It is called on every view controller, including the one(s) responsible for the currently visible UI!

Therefore, you can't just unload data arbitrarily when you get a call to `didReceiveMemoryWarning` -- the view controller might need that data if it is currently visible on the display.

The general principle is that `didReceiveMemoryWarning` can get rid of any resources it can to assist freeing up memory, but only those that aren't immediately needed. For example, in an OpenGL game you wouldn't unload textures that are currently visible on the display. However, see my last paragraph.

Typically you reload the resources by checking they are loaded when you need them, and if not, loading them.

It's not worth niling/releasing tiny resources such as a single normally sized string. You should concentrate on items taking up significant amounts of memory.

**Recent advances in behind the scenes memory management mean you're less likely to need to actually unload data these days - the operating system can unload and reload uncompressed image data and the like behind the scenes.**

As Hot Licks mentions, the simulator has an option for simulating a memory warning. It's worth triggering this memory warning at various points in your app to see how it behaves.

Comment: I'll add that the simulator allows you to simulate this warning, for testing your memory scavenging code.

Comment: Apple strongly recommends using the lazy initialization pattern to reload purged resources. Adding a brief example showing how to do that would improve your answer.

Comment: Cheers Hot Licks, added that to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Create custom getter that load data lazily. Something such as this snippet is good for non-mutithreading eviroment:

```
- (NSArray*) dataArray {
  if(_dataArray) return _dataArray;

  _dataArray = [self lordata];
  return _dataArray;
}
```

In this way data are always reloaded if you "release" them in memory warnings

Answer (score 0):

The `ViewDidLoad` method is called only once, when your ViewController is initialized. If you must reload some data to your NSArray, you should call your own methods to do that when needed.

If this array is used by various parts of the code, maybe you should think about redesigning your code structure to avoid a huge concentration of data inside only one object.

**Edit: As pointed by @occulus in the comments below, it is not called when the View is initialized, but when the View is loaded by the ViewController.. my mistake**

Comment: No, viewDidLoad is called when the view controller has loaded the view, not when it is initialised (init method). It seems a small difference but it's quite important sometimes.

Comment: Also, "only once" isn't necessarily true: older versions of iOS can unload the view on low memory conditions and hence later call viewDidLoad again. This exposes the important different between view controller initialising (which really is only once) versus the view being loaded.

Comment: You're right, @occulus ... I think I wrote erroneously about initializing and loading... I will add an edit to fix that

Comment: Rather than keeping erroneous information in the first paragraph, then retracting it later, why not just fix the first paragraph? Less confusing.

Answer (score 0):

As an example, I had an app that downloaded data to a very long table view (potentially 1000s of records).  To support this I implemented a "sparse" array, allowing empty elements that would be "faulted in" over the net when referenced (with a "downloading" indicator in the table cell while downloading).

This was rigged so that when didReceiveMemoryWarning occurred the array would be purged, using a least-recently-used algorithm to delete the oldest N% of the array.  Recovery would be automatic -- the emptied cells would reload when they were referenced.

Not that I recommend this specific scheme, but note the general features of having a lot of data, having a way to "prioritize" what should be deleted, and having a "soft" way to reload the data (ideally only reloading the parts that are needed in the near future).